# How to deal with react, react-dom, @types/react and @types/react-dom package versions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, package.json

Recently, I upgrade version of react/react-dom in my project from 16.3.2 to 16.8.6 to be able to use hooks and, with some minor changes in my code, everything went well.

But we are using typescript, and when I try to use React.useState(), typescript compiler complains and is unable to compile : `Property 'useState' does not exist on type 'typeof React'.`

I think the problem is that @types/react and @types/react-dom packages were not up-to-date. So I tried to upgrade them from 16.3.2 to 16.8.5 (16.8.6 doesn't exist for @types/react-dom).

Then I was able to use `usestate()` but everything else was broken, typescript compiler was complaining about almost every component...

My question is: what should I do ? What is the best approach to upgrade those packages ? Do versions need to be the same ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, [@types/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react) and [@types/react-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-dom) versions may not be the same.
You have to choose the correct versions based on the versions of typescript and react that you're using.

**Here's how:**

For example, imagine you are using react 17.x.y. Because of that, you would look at the 17.x.y versions of @types/react. To choose the final one, you would look at the tag next to each one of those and choose the one that matches your typescript version (tsX.Y). Imagine if you are using typescript 3.8.x. You could choose this package:

[image: @types/react version]

The same thing for @types/react-dom.

Comment: Where did you find this table?

Comment: Here, on the @types/react npm page, in the versions tab: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react?activeTab=versions

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';


export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(); 
}
```

Did you try on that way?

and you are using the right @types in your package.json

```
"@types/react": "^16.8.14",
"@types/react-dom": "16.8.3",
"typescript": "3.5.3"
```

Comment: "and you are using the right @types in your package.json" this is one of my question : how do you know what is the appropriate version of the package you need ?

And second, if I do upgrade it, I've got a least 300 error from typescript compiler to deal with, is that normal ?

Comment: No, it's not normal. Can you try remove your node_modules and do install again? What typescript version you are using?

Comment: I had typescript: 2.6.2. I upgraded it to 3.6.1 and now have only 3 errors. So that is more manageable. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Are @types/react version supposed to match react

Comment: @coler-j You must have the same version of react and react-dom but @types/react and @types/react-dom are maintained separately and won't match. Just make sure you are using the same major version.